# while loop will not execute

Tags: c, cs50

I need a while loop to only take in positive number.  I wrote a while loop but it won't execute and Im not sure what's wrong.  My code works fine with a for while loop but when I enter a negative number and run the code it prints out the input, then reprompts the user.  I just want it to re-prompt, not print the input too.

Thank you if anyone can help.

This will print the input, then reprompt the user

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    float change;

    do
    {
        change = get_float("Change: ");
        printf("%f\n", change);
    }
    while (change < 1);

}
```

This will not execute at all

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    float change;

    while (change < 1)
    {
        change = get_float("Change: ");
        printf("%f\n", change);
    }


}
```

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: Objects with automatic storage duration are not initialized by default.

Comment: I  am not a C expert... But in C# it works like that. That's why I explained why while loop is not executing.

Comment: very simple fix is needed: `float change = 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below. check the comments for explanation

Using do..while loop

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    float change;

    do
    {
        change = get_float("Change: ");

    }
    while (change < 1);
    printf("%f\n", change);

}
```

Using while loop

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    float change;
    change = get_float("Change: "); //Capture value for first time
    while (change < 1) //Check if input value is negative
    {
        change = get_float("Change: "); //If negative ask for input again

    }

    printf("%f\n", change); // If value is positive, while loop passed over and value printed


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, just stop doing the `printf` inside the loop.

In the second one, you're testing the value of `change` before you store a value in it, which is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: where should float change be moved to?

Comment: Ok ill give it go.  Thanks for helping.